# Fast data structure or algorithm to find mean of each pixel in a stack of images

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, image-processing, data-structures

I have a stack of images in which I want to calculate the mean of each pixel down the stack.

For example, let `(x_n,y_n)` be the `(x,y)` pixel in the nth image. Thus, the mean of pixel `(x,y)` for three images in the image stack is:

```
mean-of-(x,y) = (1/3) * ((x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2) + (x_3,y_3))
```

My first thought was to load all pixel intensities from each image into a data structure with a single linear buffer like so:

```
|All pixels from image 1| All pixels from image 2| All pixels from image 3|
```

To find the sum of a pixel down the image stack, I perform a series of nested for loops like so:

```
for(int col=0; col<img_cols; col++)
{
    for(int row=0; row<img_rows; row++)
    {
        for(int img=0; img<num_of_images; img++)
        {
            sum_of_px += px_buffer[(img*img_rows*img_cols)+col*img_rows+row];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically `img*img_rows*img_cols` gives the buffer element of the first pixel in the nth image and `col*img_rows+row` gives the `(x,y)` pixel that I want to find for each n image in the stack.

Is there a data structure or algorithm that will help me sum up pixel intensities down an image stack that is faster and more organized than my current implementation?

I am aiming for portability so I will not be using OpenCV and am using C++ on linux.

Comment: I don't think you're looking for a better data structure. I think you're looking for a better *algorithm*. Every pixel from every image needs to exist in memory at one point or another; the only thing a different data structure would do is reduce how much memory you're using at any given moment. I have difficulty imagining a data structure would would yield *speed* increases, short of a data structure which avoids cache-misses, but at that point, there are other things you could be doing to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks. Edited now to correct. I am really open to any suggestion that can improve performance, particularly speed.

Comment: A better solution is not to hold them in memory at the same time *at all*, and just do a pass for each image.

Comment: Use AVX for this. It will perform the multiplications and additions in parallel. Google calculating the dot product using AVX. Also look at Haswell which has a "Mused multiply and add" instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the nested loop in the question is that it's not very cache friendly.  You go skipping through memory with a long stride, effectively rendering your data cache useless.  You're going to spend a lot of time just accessing the memory.

If you can spare the memory, you can create an extra image-sized buffer to accumulate totals for each pixel as you walk through all the pixels in all the images in memory order.  Then you do a single pass through the buffer for the division.

Your accumulation buffer may need to use a larger type than you use for individual pixel values, since it has to accumulate many of them.  If your pixel values are, say, 8-bit integers, then your accumulation buffer might need 32-bit integers or floats.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a stack of pixels

```
(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)
```

is conditionally independent from a stack

```
(a_1,b_1),...,(a_n,b_n)
```

And even if they weren't (assuming a particular dataset), then modeling their interactions is a complex task and will give you only an estimate of the mean. So, if you want to compute the exact mean for each stack, you don't have any other choice but to iterate through the three loops that you supply. Languages such as Matlab/octave and libraries such as Theano (python) or Torch7 (lua) all parallelize these iterations. If you are using C++, what you do is well suited for Cuda or OpenMP. As for portability, I think OpenMP is the easier solution.

Comment: I have implemented such things in Cuda, however the mean will be passed. The overhead from Cuda may actually result in longer runtime of the program overall

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the size of the data? If you have 100000 RGB images of size 1240*370... Then wouldn't Cuda be faster?

Answer (score 2):

A portable, fast data structure **specifically for the average calculation** could be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<sometype> > > VoVoV;
VoVoV.resize(img_cols);
int i,j;
for (i=0 ; i<img_cols ; ++i)
{
  VoVoV[i].resize(img_rows);
  for (j=0 ; j<img_rows ; ++j)
  {
    VoVoV[i][j].resize(num_of_images);
    // The values of all images at this pixel are stored continguously,
    // therefore should be fast to access.
  }
}

VoVoV[col][row][img] = foo;
```

As a side note, `1/3` in your example will evaluate to `0` which is not what you want.

For fast summation/averaging you can now do:

```
sometype sum = 0;
std::vector<sometype>::iterator it     = VoVoV[col][row].begin();
std::vector<sometype>::iterator it_end = VoVoV[col][row].end();
for ( ; it != it_end ; ++it)
  sum += *it;
sometype avg = sum / num_of_images; // or similar for integers; check for num_of_images==0
```

Basically you should not rely that the compiler would optimize away the repeated calculation of always the same offsets.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the 1/3. I was more focused on getting my idea across correctly!

Comment: A vector of vectors of vectors is going to be very slow, since it's so indirect.